# What is the difference between Event.REMOVED and Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE?

Tags: actionscript-3

What is the difference between Event.REMOVED and Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE?

I thought when you have:

```
removeChild(mySpriteInstance);
```

- that this removes the item from the stage...is there a different kind of removed??

For example, if I am trying to "clean up" after an item is removed for the garbage collector...should I be listening for:

```
Event.REMOVED
```

or

```
Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REMOVED is called even if the displayobject is not on the stage:

```
var childA : Sprite = new Sprite();
var childB : Sprite = new Sprite();
childA.addChild(childB);
childA.removeChild(childB); // Event dispatched on childB
```

childA was never in the stage display list, neither was childB.

Edit:

You can always use a weak reference in your listener (The last param as true):

```
addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, onRemoved, false, 0, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, will accept in 5 minutes. So in general, is "removed" more useful instead of "removed_from_stage" for garbage collection?

Comment: Either, depends really ( I mostly use a "destroy" function to clear things up rather that using an event ) Also I tend to be slightly lazy and use a weak reference ( See my edit )

Comment: Do keep in mind that `Event.REMOVED` bubbles and can generate multiple calls of a listener if you aren't specific.